# Extract previous specific day based on date

Tags: r

Is there a specific way to extract specific day based on the date passed. Example
if the user pass Sys.Date(), the user should get the previous date which was saturday. In case if today is Saturday, the user should get today's date itself since it is saturday

```
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2021-02-11"
```

Here I need what is the date on the previous Saturday of this date(today). SO the expected output is below which is Saturaday

```
[1] "2021-02-06"
```

In Case if

Answer (score 2):

You can use `floor_date()` from `lubridate`. Note that your day of the week may be regional, so 6 may or may not be Saturday for everybody (but you can set the `week_start` optional argument).

```r
library(lubridate)

x <- as.Date("2021-02-06")
floor_date(x, "week", 6)
# [1] "2021-02-06"

x <- Sys.Date()
floor_date(x, "week", 6)
# [1] "2021-02-06"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
x <- as.Date("2021-02-11")
x - 8 + which(format(seq(x - 7, by=1, length.out = 7), "%u") == 6)
#x - 8 + which(format(seq(x - 7, by=1, length.out = 7), "%a") == "Sat") #Alternative depending on locale
#[1] "2021-02-06"
```

Or if the current day counts already:

```
x <- as.Date("2021-02-06")
x - 7 + which(format(seq(x - 6, by=1, length.out = 7), "%u") == 6)
#[1] "2021-02-06"
```

Or maybe:

```
x <- seq(as.Date("2021-02-04"), by=1, length.out = 7)
x - rep(0:6, 2)[as.integer(format(x, "%u"))+2]
#[1] "2021-01-30" "2021-01-30" "2021-02-06" "2021-02-06" "2021-02-06"
#[6] "2021-02-06" "2021-02-06"
```

Or with a lookup vector:

```
x <- seq(as.Date("2021-02-04"), by=1, length.out = 7)
LU <- c(2:6, 0:1)
x - LU[as.integer(format(x, "%u"))]
#[1] "2021-01-30" "2021-01-30" "2021-02-06" "2021-02-06" "2021-02-06"
#[6] "2021-02-06" "2021-02-06"
```

Comment: great. But if the date is ````"2021-02-06"````,it is showing as ````"2021-01-30"````. But it should still show as ````"2021-02-06"````

Comment: `"2021-02-06"` is *not* previous to `"2021-02-06"`. But if you want `"2021-02-06"` change the `8` to a `7` and the `9` to a `8`.

Comment: Thanks I tried with ````x - 8 + which(format(seq(x - 7, by=1, length.out = 6), "%u") == 6)````. But still getting ````"2021-01-30"````

Comment: Oh yes, still one to much. Please see update.

Answer (score 1):

The following is based on a formula given in one of the zoo package vignettes but does not depend on that package or any other package.

Suppose x is a vector of `Date` class and d is a day of the week where Sunday = 0, Monday = 1 and so on.  Then

```
X0 <- as.Date(d - 4, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

falls on day of the week d so we can count how many weeks since then including any fraction of a week and then round down and multiply by 7 adding that to X0 to get the prior Date falling on day of the week d (or x if it is already that day of the week).

Thus if an element of Date class vector x is on day of the week d then the following returns x for that element and otherwise it gives the prior Date on that day of the week.

Regarding the code, if zoo is loaded then the `origin=` argument could optionally be omitted.

No packages are used, the function is vectorized so x may be a `Date` vector and not just a single `Date` and there is no dependence on locale or time zone.

```
# x is Date vector, d is weekday where 0 = Sun, 1 = Mon, etc.
prev <- function(x, d = 0) 7 * floor(as.numeric(x - d + 4) / 7) + 
  as.Date(d - 4, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Using Saturday, i.e. day of the week 6, as an example,

```
x <- as.Date("2000-01-08") + 0:8
x
## [1] "2000-01-08" "2000-01-09" "2000-01-10" "2000-01-11" "2000-01-12"
## [6] "2000-01-13" "2000-01-14" "2000-01-15" "2000-01-16"

weekdays(x)
## [1] "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday" 
## [7] "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"   

p <- prev(x, 6)  # 6 means Saturday
p
## [1] "2000-01-08" "2000-01-08" "2000-01-08" "2000-01-08" "2000-01-08"
## [6] "2000-01-08" "2000-01-08" "2000-01-15" "2000-01-15"

weekdays(p)
## [1] "Saturday" "Saturday" "Saturday" "Saturday" "Saturday" "Saturday" "Saturday"
## [8] "Saturday" "Saturday"
```